# Cannot figure out why a TreeView builds as a mirror in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, treeview

I'm having a weird problem with a TreeView in JavaFX.

The application that I use this in builds the branches from web-based data so it takes some time to populate the TreeView. But as it's populating, the branches show up **at the top *and* the bottom** but at the bottom it's only text and not actual TreeItems.

I created minimal re-producible code if anyone wants to try it for themselves. I published the minimal code to GitHub and you can [clone it from here](https://github.com/EasyG0ing1/TreeViewProblem).

[This screen capture](https://youtube.com/shorts/cjdVELIEkcA) will also show the problem.

Here are the classes that will reproduce the issue:

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    private TreeItem<TreeNode> root;
    private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        root = new TreeItem<>(new TreeNode("Root", false));
        TreeView<TreeNode> treeView = new TreeView<>(root);
        treeView.setCellFactory(param -> new CellFactory());
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(treeView);
        double width = 500;
        double height = 800;
        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(ap);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(width);
        stage.setHeight(height);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });
        treeView.setPrefWidth(width);
        treeView.setPrefHeight(height);
        ap.setPrefWidth(width);
        ap.setPrefHeight(height);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 30.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
        stage.show();
        new Thread(buildTree()).start();
    }

    private String getName() {
        int low = 100;
        int high = 9999;
        return "Node(" + random.nextInt(low, high) + ")";
    }

    private Runnable buildTree() {
        return ()->{
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                boolean checkBoxNode = x % 2 == 0;
                root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new TreeNode(getName(), checkBoxNode)));
                sleep(500);
            }
        };
    }

    private void sleep(long time) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

CellFactory:

```
public class CellFactory extends TreeCell<TreeNode> {
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public CellFactory() {
        checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setOnAction(event -> {
            TreeNode item = getItem();
            if (item != null) {
                item.setSelected(checkBox.isSelected());
            }
        });

        itemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, treeNode) -> {
            if (treeNode != null) {
                checkBox.setVisible(treeNode.isCheckBoxNode());
            }
        }));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(TreeNode treeNode, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(treeNode, empty);
        if (empty || treeNode == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else {
            checkBox.setSelected(treeNode.isSelected());
            setText(treeNode.toString());
            setGraphic(checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

TreeNode:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private String name;
    private boolean selected = true;
    private boolean checkBoxNode;

    public TreeNode(String name, boolean checkBoxNode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checkBoxNode = checkBoxNode;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isCheckBoxNode() {
        return checkBoxNode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

**A bug in your code causes the observed issue**

Cells are reused, and must be updated correctly in the `updateItem` call.

You set the text of the cell when the cell is not empty.  But, you don't unset the text (set it to null) if the cell which was previously empty is updated to an empty value.

See the fixed code below:

```
protected void updateItem(TreeNode treeNode, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(treeNode, empty);
    if (empty || treeNode == null) {
        setText(null);  // <-- text for previous associated 
                        //     item needs to be cleared for empty cells.
        setGraphic(null);       
    } else {
        checkBox.setSelected(treeNode.isSelected());
        setText(treeNode.toString());  // <--- text has been set here.
        setGraphic(checkBox);
    }
}
```

**Unrelated problems or confusing things in your example**

You should never access or modify elements associated with the active scene graph from another thread, you should use `Platform.runLater` to add new TreeItems on the JavaFX thread. It is not the root of your issue, but it is a problem that should be fixed.

Your CellFactory is confusingly named, it is not a cell factory, it is a Cell (you can see that because it extends TreeCell). The factory is the complete callback for the lambda that produces new cells.

The TreeNode class is confusingly named, it isn't a JavaFX node. Yes, it is a node of the tree in the data model, but it is quite confusing to me given the context.  It might be OK for others, I don't know.

**FAQ**

> I don't fully understand why the text from a previous TreeItem would show up at the bottom of the TreeView.

The creation and placement of the cells is part of the internal `TreeView` implementation.  You don't have to understand how the internal details work unless you want to change the `TreeView` internal implementation in the JavaFX library (which you don't want to do).  The only way to understand that is to review the code and reverse engineer the design from the implementation.

You only need to ensure that you are updating the cell visuals correctly when the item backing the cell changes.

I guess, internally, the TreeView might be moving cells around; sometimes creating new ones and sometimes reusing existing ones.  But it doesn't really matter how it manages the cells; as long as you update the cell correctly, the correct values will show.

The strange behaviour that occurred in the example in your question was due to bugs in your code and not bugs in the JavaFX `TreeView` implementation.

> Also, which class names would you have gone with instead of `CellFactory` and `TreeNode` ?

Probably something related to your problem domain (which I don't know).  If you want some pretty generic names then:

- `CellFactory` -> `CustomTreeCell` or `CheckManagementTreeCell`
- `TreeNode` -> `TreeItemData`.

Comment: Thank you, that did fix the problem. But I am no better off for it, because I don't fully understand why the text from a previous TreeItem would show up at the bottom of the TreeView. Also, which class names would you have gone with instead of CellFactory and TreeNode ?

Comment: Added an FAQ section.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You're right, of course, understanding the workings under the hood isn't necessary ... just use the classes as they were designed to be used and all should be well... but curiosity ... as they say ... ☺

Comment: What do you think of the name `ItemClass` instead of `TreeNode`?

Comment: As mentioned it depends on your domain (which I don't know) and is subjective.  Maybe `ItemClass` is OK if it represents a category or type or item (in which case I would call it `ItemCategory`).  Pick and use the name which makes the most sense to you given your knowledge of the domain.